# add bottom border to all table data cells

Tags: html, css

is there anyway I can avoid writing the border specs into every table data cell?

```
<table width='800' bgcolor='grey' cellspacing='0'
style="border-bottom-style:solid; border-bottom-width:1px; border-color:black">  <tr>
<td style="border-bottom-style:solid; border-bottom-width:1px;">
First Name:<td style="border-bottom-style:solid;
 border-bottom-width:1px;"> {$info['firstname']}</td></tr>
 <tr><td style="border-bottom-style:solid; 
border-bottom-width:1px;">Last Name:
<td style="border-bottom-style:solid; border-bottom-width:1px;">
{$info['lastname']}</td> </tr>
<tr><td style="border-bottom-style:solid; border-bottom-width:1px;">
email:<td       style="border-bottom-style:solid; border-bottom-width:1px;">
{$info['email']}</td></tr>
<tr><td>password:<td>********</td></tr>
```

Answer (score 6):

This is basic CSS. Put this in the head of your document:

```
<style type="text/css">
    td {
      border-bottom-style:solid;
      border-bottom-width:1px;
    }
</style>
```

This will apply to all `<td>` in your page. If you want it to apply to certain table cells or certain tables only then you will need to start using more advanced selectors. But any CSS tutorial can show you how to do that.

BTW, you can do this with your table too:

```
table {
  border-bottom-style:solid; 
  border-bottom-width:1px; 
  border-color:black
}
```

Or use [shorthand](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/shorthand/):

```
table {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

You may want to have a look into a [CSS-Tutorial](http://www.brainjar.com/css/using/).

Answer (score 2):

```
<style>
    table td
    {
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
table { border-bottom: solid 1px #000000;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS.

```
td {
    border-bottom: solid 1px black;
}
```

It is recommended that you write the CSS in another file and include it in your webpage using:

```
<link rel=StyleSheet href="example.css"/>
```

More about CSS here: http://www.w3schools.com/css

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be this...

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      table{
        background-color: grey;
        width: 800px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        border-spacing: 0;
        border-collapse: collapse;
      }
      table tr td{
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table cellspacing='0'>  
      <tr>
        <td>First Name:</td>
        <td> {$info['firstname']}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Last Name:</td>
        <td>{$info['lastname']}</td> 
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>email:</td>
        <td>{$info['email']}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>password:</td>
        <td>********</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```